# What happens if I pass function body instead of a function name to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I know the correct way of using setTimeout is as follows:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert('hi!');}, 3000);
```

or define the function outside, and pass the reference:

```
var foo=function(){alert('hi!');}
setTimeout(foo, 3000);
```

What happens if I write it as:

```
setTimeout(alert('hi!'), 3000);
```

It looks like `alert('hi!')` was executed correctly.

Comment: Did you mean to quote that last one, as in eval'ed, right now it doesn't work, it just executes the function right away ?

Comment: I know it's just an example, but are you using `alert()` with node.js? Anyway, if you want to pass just the function body (or individual statements) to `setTimeout()` you need to pass a string: `setTimeout("alert('hi!')", 3000);` but this is _not_ recommended.

Comment: Sure, `alert('hi!')` gets executed correctly, but it's not delayed by 3 seconds. It will send the alert as soon as it reaches that line of the code.

Comment: @adeneo no I meant it wasn't even quoted. i directly called a function with its parameters in the place of an anonymous function definition.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah in reality i used console.log(). but it was able to run without quotes

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it'd be great if you (or someone else) can explain what exactly happened

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`alert("hi")` gets executed *immediately* and its result, `undefined`, is passed to `setTimeout`...

Now, if you simply want to avoid a wrapper while specifying your arguments, try this:

```js
 setTimeout(alert, 3000, "hi!");
```

Comment: There are some interoperability issues with your last form of `setTimeout()` if not using a modern browser.

Comment: Thanks! Verified with node.js and good to know for the first time that you can append parameters in setTimeout!

Answer (score 0):

In the first two examples the function will be invoked inside the `setTimeout` function after defined delay as a callback function while the third example will be executed immediately.